# what are the disadvantages of my bad naming for images?

Tags: php, mysql

I created an image based website that contains more than 10,000 images. The images' links look like this:

```
http://example.com/image/1.jpg

http://example.com/image/2.jpg

http://example.com/image/3.jpg
```

Can hackers eat my bandwidth by downloading the sequence over and over? How can I get over this problem using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Is it a real problem? Even if you have one image url you can download it continuously

Comment: Use random image names.

Comment: @zerkms so I can keep it this way?

Comment: @Fady: we don't know the original task so we cannot estimate if it's a good solution or not

Comment: @zerkms It's a huge album for an online library, it works fine but I'm asking about the way I named the images, is it safe?

Comment: you don't even need to be a hacker to do what you describe. More appropriately may be to ask what advantages there are in naming your images with SEO in mind

Comment: @KaiQing SEO is not important in my case, I'm worried about security issues only

Comment: @jake - we don't know about the quality of his site. Any fool following a basic scraping tutorial could build a site that technically stores thousands of images. The real question is why he doesn't just move to a host with unlimited bandwidth? I have a basic dreamhost account that doesn't restrict me in any way.

Comment: and fady - I'm not trying to focus on SEO specifically, just that naming your images sequentially is obvious. Naming them with SEO in mind is effectively the same as assigning a random ID to the image name, but it has added benefits. Viewing an image is no threat to security. If it was, remove the image or only allow it to be served indirectly via a script on your site. You can block direct access to whole directories using htaccess, for example

Comment: @jake - You're right of course. But CDN might cost more is all. I'm not sure what kind of traffic he is getting so I couldn't say one is better than the other. I'm sure my "unlimited" DH account isn't really unlimited. It may throttle eventually but I've never seen it happen yet.

Comment: @jake - Yeah I have. We often use amazon s3 for clients. It's pennies per gig, but if he's asking because he is seeing some rampant bandwidth spikes like in the millions per day it might surpass hosting costs eventually. If the options were free, but you may be throttled versus pennies per gig but you know you will push the data beyond the cost of monthly hosting, which he will likely be paying anyhow, then hosted makes some sense. CDNs are useful though. I'm not arguing with you. Just pointing out an alternative. heh - pennies per TB. VERY unlikely he will threaten that number

Comment: @JakeGould , it's prevent download by obvious sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can hackers eat my bandwidth by downloading the sequence over and
>   over? How can I get over this problem using PHP and MySQL.

Anyone who can see an image only can download that image. Not just hackers. Adults, children, the invalid, the disabled, robots, etc… If you have a website & someone or something accessing that site then you have bandwidth issues. Period. So this is a massive non-issue.

As far as file naming goes, the naming scheme really has no impact on that. Someone who scripts a crawler will just crawl the raw HTML to grab the image URLs & take it from there.

That said, if you are concerned about bandwidth being used, then you should look into using [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store your images and [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to deliver your images via a CDN. A CDN will quickly deliver your content to users without slamming your main server directly.

But past that, you really need to understand that if you have a website on the Internet, the content on it will be accessed. And it has nothing to do with “hacking” in any way.